# Using Sql Compact 4 with Asp.net MVC3

Tags: visual-studio-2010, asp.net-mvc-3, c#-4.0, sql-server-ce

How do I create an application with SQL Server Compact 4 and Asp.net MVC3?

After creating an application MVC3 tried to add a new item of type SQL Compact Database (*. sdf) but it does not even appear in the list.

Comment: Which version of Visual Studio are you using? SP1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that you have [Visual Studio 2010 SP1](http://www.microsoft.com/web/gallery/install.aspx?appid=VS2010SP1Pack) installed (or [Visual Web Developer Express 2010 SP1](http://www.microsoft.com/web/gallery/install.aspx?appid=vwd)). It contains the tooling support necessary to work with SQL CE 4.

Comment: I am using the Visual Studio 2010 Web Express version:
Version 10.0.30319.1 RTMRel

Comment: Same applies to Express. The easies way to upgrade is to use Web Platform Installer and select to install SP1.

Comment: You can use this link: http://www.microsoft.com/web/gallery/install.aspx?appid=vwd